# PHP Data Between Static Methods of Different Classes

Tags: php, oop, wordpress, static-methods

I'm writing a Wordpress plugin, and struggling with OOP concepts in PHP. What I want to do is relatively simple, I think, so I don't know whether I'm barking up the wrong tree with the way I'm trying to organise things.

Here's the basic scenario:
I have created a self-contained class to implement a shortcode function. This makes use of static methods because I didn't think there was any need to instantiate an instance of the class for this purpose.

This seems to work fine. However, I need to implement a few other components, namely a 'Shortcode Helper' plugin for the post Editor, a Widget and an Options page. These logically break down into discrete collections of functions, so it seems to make sense to group each into its own class. Again, though, I'm not sure if they need to be instantiated. The complication is that the static functions inside each class need to share common data, and I'd like to be able to call static functions in one class from static functions in another class, so, for example, all classes can share default settings, and I can, for example, reuse the control-panel of the shortcode helper as the widget control-panel.

Is this actually possible to achieve with static functions? I've not had any success calling a static function in one class from a static function in another so far. Am I just barking up the wrong tree here. In the past I've done this kind of thing using procedural methods, but I'm trying to to move towards a more OOP-based approach.

Sorry for the long message.

Any advice much appreciated.

Cheers,

Alex

Answer (score 3):

> Class Oriented Programming is like buying a car to let it sit in the driveway, opening and closing its doors repeatedly, jumping around on the seats, occasionally turning on the windshield wipers, yet never once turning the ignition key and taking it for a drive. It is missing the point entirely.
>
> [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Please read the abovelinked article. What you are attempting is procedural programming with global state. OOP actually has very little to do with it.

Comment: Hi deceze,thanks for getting back to me. Very informative article. I've been writing PHP for some years, but just started to dip my toes in the OOP world (or not, as you point out). I'm finding it quite hard to get my head round the basic principles involved, I must admit. I'll do some more reading, and maybe look into the Singleton pattern. Looks like that might be what I need. Thanks again.

Comment: @Alex Nope, Singleton is exactly *not* what you need. Because it usually means that you have code like `Foo::getInstance()` everywhere. Which is just a procedural function call and foregoes the advantages of OOP, as laid out in the article. Learn *dependency injection*.

Comment: But surely if I don't need multiple instances of an object with their own properties, I shouldn't be creating multiple instances... I mean, If I need to use the same methods and static properties in more than one place, surely it doesn't make sense to instantiate multiple objects. That seems like a waste of server resources to me...

Comment: Then instantiate it once and *inject* it where needed! :)

Comment: I'm guessing you'd disagree with the writer of [this article:](http://phpadvocate.com/blog/2011/04/php-using-a-singleton-pattern-with-oop/), deceze.

Comment: Yup, I'll disagree with it. :) The starting point is not bad (don't instantiate a new object every time), the conclusion falls short. Calling a static method to get an instance is the problem. As outlined in my article, that creates code coupling and/or global state. In the interest of decoupling and testability, you want to limit this. The answer is to instantiate the object once and simply pass it around. This is tricky too, as it requires you to manage the injection graph, but solves many other problems (modularity, extensibility, testability).

Comment: Cool, got it working now. I'm instantiating my utility object once, then passing the object in as an argument to the constructor function when I instantiate the other objects. Seems to work fine. I guess that's what you meant above.

Comment: Yup, exactly. Keep things self contained, pass dependencies in.

Comment: Cool. Lighting-fast reply! Thanks again for the tips.